# Add analytics to a desktop application

Tags: html, google-analytics, analytics, offline

I have developed a desktop application using HTML 5 and node web-kit .

I would like to track parts of the app , such as how long its used , clicks ect.

I would like the analytics system to work both on and offline (storing data until its on-line).

Is there anything that I could use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) allows you to track everything that can send an http request. You need to generate a unqiue client id to group pageviews into session (the part is usually done by the Javascript tracker which does not help you) and can then choose between various interaction types and their related data to be added as parameters in a request to the Google Analytics server.

As far as offline capabilites, there is a "queue time" parameter that allows you to send delayed calls to GA. However as per documentation that delay is 4 hours at most (intended for Smartphones and Tablets that temporarily lose connection rather than to work permanently offline).

In the end it depends what data you need - you might just as well send calls to your own server and log them in a csv file and feed that to [Klipfolio](http://www.klipfolio.com/) or some other dashboard solution (or even use Excel if you expect a low data volume).

Comment: I think sending calls to a server would be best and easiest . Any idea on how to send a call to the server when the app is opened